# IBOutlet constraints won't align button upon load in iPad application

Tags: ios, uibutton, constraints, autolayout

I have a UIButton that's presented on top of another view (both are created via a xib). The constraints for the UIButton are placed programmatically.

[image]

The button is an alpha. Meaning, it only appears if the user clicks upon the view. When it first appears it's misaligned, like so:

[image]

But upon click the button is fine:

[image]

I've traced the autolayout stack in the console and there are no signals of ambiguity. Not sure what the problem since this isn't my code. I'm thinking about just deleting the button and reimplementing it since its constraints were created via IBOutlet by the other programmer (shoot me in the head).

Here's the code:

The below establishes the buttons state when it's clicked on. The reason why I've included it is because the properties _primaryTrailing and _primaryAlignCenterX are both NSLayoutConstraints.

```
- (void)setState:(kStepState)state
{
    _state = state;

    switch (state) {
        case kStepStateWatchModel:
            [self setInstruction:@"Watch Model Scenario for this Part"
                    primaryTitle:@"Model Scenario"
                  secondaryTitle:nil];
            _primaryTrailing.active =
            NO;
            _primaryAlignCenterX.active = YES;
            break;
        case kStepStatePractice:
            [self setInstruction:@"Start your first Practice for this Activity Part"
                    primaryTitle:@"Practice"
                  secondaryTitle:@"Model Scenario"];
            break;
        case kStepStateViewPractices:
            [self setInstruction:@"Pick up where you left off"
                    primaryTitle:@"My Practices"
                  secondaryTitle:@"Model Scenario"];
            break;
//        case :
//            [self setInstruction:@"Need a Refresher? (Placeholder copy)"
//                    primaryTitle:@"Model Scenario"
//                  secondaryTitle:nil];
//            break;
        case kStepStateWatchSubmission:
            [self setInstruction:@"View your Submission for this Part"
                    primaryTitle:@"My Submission"
                  secondaryTitle:@"Model Scenario"];
            break;
//        case :
//            [self setInstruction:@"Resubmit to this PART"
//                    primaryTitle:@"My Submission"
//                  secondaryTitle:nil];
//            break;

        default:
            break;
    }
}
```

Comment: None of the code shown sets any constraints nor sets he frame for the button.

Comment: Corrected. Apologies for the mistake.

Comment: Your first picture looks exactly like your screen shot from IB except the "model scenario" text is not visible - are you inactivating the appropriate constraints in the first instance?

Comment: It didn't even occur to me that the programmer assigned the IB Action to that button rather than the model scenario. Makes sense.